# Flutter: How to update state of child (and parent) widget from child widget (parent widget gets update, child does not)

Tags: flutter, dart, state, setstate, stateful

I have created myself a widget which creates either a form switch with text or just returns the switch. Now I want to use this widget called `PlatformSwitch` (child) multiple times in my filter (parent).

In order to have to correct selected values in my filter I need to pass the selected values (either `true` or `false`) back to the filter from each switch. I have already tried to solve this but I am simply not able to adapt the solutions from google to my code.

The onChange method gets fired even with the correct value I have selected, however the value passed to the child again is the old value. How can this be?

I already tried to wrap my `PlatformSwitch` in an `Obx` from `GetX` but this leads to the exact same problem. Does anyone know how to update the child value again?

Printed values:

```
flutter: Selected: false <-- Initialized
flutter: State update: true <-- Updated
flutter: Selected: false <-- Reinitialized with wrong value!
```

Filter (parent):

```
class FilterModal extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterModal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterModal> createState() => _FilterModalState();
}

class _FilterModalState extends State<FilterModal> {
  bool showExpiredProducts = false;

  _FilterModalState();

  final FilterController filterController = Get.put(FilterController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PlatformSwitch(
          selected: showExpiredProducts,
          onlySwitch: false,
          prefix: "Abgelaufen Angebote anzeigen",
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print("State update: " + value.toString());
              showExpiredProducts = value;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

PlatformSwitch (child):

```
class PlatformSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  String? prefix;
  bool onlySwitch;
  bool selected;
  ValueChanged onChanged;

  PlatformSwitch(
      {Key? key,
      this.selected = false,
      this.onlySwitch = true,
      this.prefix,
      required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  _PlatformSwitchState createState() => _PlatformSwitchState(
      selected,
      onlySwitch,
      prefix,
      onChanged);
}

class _PlatformSwitchState extends State<PlatformSwitch> {
  String? prefix;
  bool onlySwitch;
  bool selected;
  ValueChanged onChanged;

  _PlatformSwitchState(
      this.selected,
      this.onlySwitch,
      this.prefix,
      this.onChanged);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Selected: " + selected.toString());

    if (!onlySwitch) {
      return platformFormRowSwitch();
    }

    return platformSwitch();
  }

  platformFormRowSwitch() {
    return Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [Text(prefix!)],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [platformSwitch()],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  platformSwitch() {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return Switch(
        value: selected,
        onChanged: onChanged
      );
    }

    return CupertinoSwitch(
      value: selected,
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`State` outlives `StatefulWidget`. When widget instance is recreated with new parameters, old state instance is kept.

To get updated data in state, you have two options:

- access data from widget using `widget.something`
- update state's fields in [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html)